# How to use text from a cell as a reference a different sheet in Excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to use the text manually entered into A1 to reference the same cell from various different sheets. For example..

If A1 contains the text "dogs" then the formula in B1 would effectively read =dogs!D3 and reference cell D3 in the sheet named "dogs." If the text in A1 is changed to "cats" then B1 would automatically adjust to =cats!D3

Excel 2013. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use `INDIRECT()`. 
This function accepts a cell address as an argument,
and returns the contents of the named call. 
For example,

```
=INDIRECT("D3")
```

is essentially equivalent to

```
=D3
```

and, likewise,

```
=INDIRECT("cats!D3")
```

is essentially equivalent to

```
=cats!D3
```

So the simple answer is to put

```
=INDIRECT(A1 & "!D3")
```

into call B1. 
`&` is the string concatenation operator, so, if A1 contains "dogs",
then `A1 & "!D3"` evaluates to `dogs!D3`
and the `INDIRECT` function returns the contents of that cell
from the "dogs" sheet.

That's the simple answer. 
It's fine if your sheet names don't have space(s) in them. 
But, if you have a sheet name that contains space(s), e.g., "fat cat",
you need to quote that name (with single quotes!) to reference the cell;
for example,

```
='fat cat'!D3
```

So, to handle this contingency, we just add quotes to the formula:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "'!D3")
```

Comment: @GeneB Please mark this as the solution.

Comment: If my sheet is named as a date, i.e. 20-Feb-2021, then inside the INDIRECT function this date is converted to a number - INDIRECT(44255&"!A5") and the formula stops to work.

Comment: P.S. just found - put the date into TEXT function:

=IFERROR(INDIRECT("'"&TEXT(A209,"dd-mmm-yyyy")&"'"&"!$E$15"),"")